# How to fix "ORA-01031" while creating view on "SYS.CDEF$" from another user Oracle Database 19c

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

Starting from Oracle Database 19c `"O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY"` parameter has been de-supported. Now our code creating view on `SYS.CDEF$` (from another user )is failing with `ORA-01031` insufficient privileges error.

The user has the following privileges `SELECT CATALOGUE ROLE`, `EXECUTE CATALOGUE ROLE`, `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY`, `CREATE VIEW` and `CREATE ANY VIEW`.

sample:

```
create view v_Cdef$ as select * from sys.cdef$

ORA-01031 error while creating view on SYS.CDEF$
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Edit your post for clarification

Comment: What happens if you run `select * from sys.cdef$` with the same user?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the full script, I can't reproduce

```
SQL> conn /@db19_pdb1 as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> drop user demo cascade;

User dropped.

SQL> create user demo identified by demo;

User created.

SQL> grant SELECT ANY DICTIONARY, CREATE VIEW , create session to demo;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn demo/demo@db19_pdb1
Connected.

SQL> create view v_Cdef$ as select * from sys.cdef$;

View created.
```